# Save and update object in same transaction

Tags: hibernate, jakarta-ee

my requirement is that i want to **save** an object and **after saving** it **update** that object with other related data (all in **same transaction**, since i am using **@Transcational** annotation on **service class level**), here's a code snippet:

#### Service:

```
@Service@Transactional
public class MyService {

    public Employee addEmployee(Employee employee) throws Exception, {

        try {

            employeeDao.addEmployee(employee);

            MessagingGroup messagingGroup = messageGroupDao.getMsgGroupByID(1);
            EmployeeGroup employeeGroup = new EmployeeGroup();
            employeeGroup.setEmployee(employee); // the saved employee
            employeeGroup.setMessageGroup(messagingGroup);
            employeeGroup.setJoinType(false);
            Set < EmployeeGroup > employeeGroups = new HashSet < EmployeeGroup > ();
            employeeGroups.add(employeeGroup);

            employee.setEmployeeGroups(employeeGroups);
            updateEmployee(employee);

            return employee;
        } catch (AccessDeniedException ad) {
            throw new AccessDeniedException("Access Denied!");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("Error Occurred While Adding Employee: " + e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }

    }
}
```

#### DAO:

```
public class MyDao {

    public void addEmployee(Employee employee) {
        employee = (Employee) getCurrentSession().merge(employee);
        getCurrentSession().save(employee);
    }

    public void updateEmployee(Employee employee) {
        getCurrentSession().update(employee);
    }

}
```

#### Issue:

In the service, after saving the object and trying to update, I found out that the ID of the saved object is 0 so it suppose that it's not saved (I guess so because the transaction is not yet committed before update since both save and update are in same transaction), so it tries to insert it again, so what is the best way to avoid that, merging then saving all at once? Or make the add and the update in separate transactions, or use `saveOrUpdate` method? I am confused.

please advise, thanks.

Comment: Are the rest of the fields (apart from the pk) being saved? It is strange that it is 0 in that case. What kind of column is the pk? Have you defined it as auto increment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fixed it by changing the save dao method to return the saved object (with the generated identifier):

```
public Employee addEmployee(Employee employee) {
            employee = (Employee) getCurrentSession().merge(employee);
            getCurrentSession().save(employee);
            return employee;
        }
```

and in the service:

```
            employee=employeeDao.addEmployee(employee); // to get the generated identifier

            MessagingGroup messagingGroup = messageGroupDao.getMsgGroupByID(1);
            EmployeeGroup employeeGroup = new EmployeeGroup();
            employeeGroup.setEmployee(employee); // the saved employee
            employeeGroup.setMessageGroup(messagingGroup);
            employeeGroup.setJoinType(false);
            Set < EmployeeGroup > employeeGroups = new HashSet < EmployeeGroup > ();
            employeeGroups.add(employeeGroup);

            employee.setEmployeeGroups(employeeGroups);
            updateEmployee(employee);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try to use @Transactional annotation on your Dao as well.

Comment: on the dao class level you mean ?

Comment: tried it on add and update methods in dao with no luck, same problem.

Comment: I assume you are using spring framework, if so you have to put @Transcational annotations to the interfaces not the implementation classes.